# Server, Database or Code Issue? Magento backend rewrites itself with a index.php which doesnt work

Tags: admin, backend, overrides, base-url

I will be honest and admit my cross posting in serverfault.com but the reason is that I believe it is a server fault, and now I am looking for proof to present to my dreaded hosting providers, GoDaddy...

My magento was working a dream, all of a sudden, when logining into

```
mysite.com/mixitup/
```

after the login, it changes to

```
mysite.com/index.php/mixitup/dashboard/index/key/812b0641da.... etc,
```

however if I change the path to

```
mysite.com/mixitup/dashboard/index/key/812b0641da... etc
```

then it shows the dasboard, but upon clicking anything such as catalogue > manage products the index.php is inserted again, leaving

```
mysite.com/index.php/mixitup/catalog_product/index/key/f0e2d249eca781e... etc
```

Strangly, this has suddenly taken affect on 2 independent magento sites on one server. They share a .htaccess file on the route, however this hasn't changed to cause the problem. It's a godaddy shared server so my options here are limited.

Any thoughts on what may have changed this? or how to fix it?

Here is a copy of my .htaccess file (sorry to dump)

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

#php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

# Insert filter on all content
###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
#BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
#BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
#BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don't compress images
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
#Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

RewriteBase /

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

AddDefaultCharset Off
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

#FileETag none
```

**WHAT I'VE ALSO TRIED**

I just tried restoring last Mondays backup, of both database and data and no such luck... can I therefore presume that it's a server config change? The way its handling URL Rewrites? Mod_Rewrites? or the .htaccess file itself?

Henry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**APACHE UPGRADE CAUSED ISSUE**

Hosting provider moved me from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 which officially goosed up my Magento Site !

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the system config setting `web/seo/use_rewrites` if the Magento frontend adds the *index.php* to rendered links.

The option can be found in the admin panel under

```
System > Config > Web > Search Engine Optimization
```

Be aware that the setting can be specified on a store view scope, so a setting there might be overwriting your default and/or website scope setting.

You find all the values for that setting in the database run the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/seo/use_rewrites';
```

On a related note, in the admin area it's hardcoded, that is, Magento will always add the *index.php* to the rendered links.

Comment: Hi vinai, the store view works fine, its just the backend that suddently has failed. In fact, its failed on a few sites on 1 server. Which makes me think thats its a server issue. Correct?

Comment: The only way it could have suddenly failed is if there was a rather intrusive modification changing stuff up. Magento has always required the index.php be in the admin URLs.

Comment: The store view always renders the index.php into the links, see ```Mage_Core_Model_Store::_updatePathUseRewrites()```.

Answer (score 1):

Adminrewrite are hardcoded, seo rewrite will not help.

I fixed it on godaddy by installing this free extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/clockworkgeek/extension/3692/clockworkgeek_adminrewrites

and read comment by djzubah :
insert table manually

Hope this helped, I spent 2 days trying everything else
Thanks to clockworkgeek it is now working.